# Next.js default component value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am trying to create a global variable that all components are rendered with by default and set that default value but I'm not sure how to do the 2nd part. Here's what I have so far in my `_app.tsx`:

```
import { AppProps } from "next/app";
import type { NextComponentType  } from 'next'
import Blue from "../components/blue";
 
type CProps = AppProps & {
   Component: NextComponentType & {model?: string }
};
 
const MyApp = ({
   Component,
   pageProps: { ...pageProps },
}: CProps) => {
   return (
       <>
           {Component.model === 'blue' ? (
               <Blue>
                   <Component {...pageProps} />
               </Blue>
           ) : (
               <Component {...pageProps} />
           )}
       </>
   );
};
```

But this obviously doesn't give me a default value for `model`. It just creates that variable with null value for all the components. How do I set the value?

Side question: Is this better done using React Context?

Edit 1:
This is how the component sets the model value if it does not want to use the default value:

```
const ComponentFoo = () => {
   return (
       <>Test</>
   );
};
 
ComponentFoo.model = 'red'
 
export default ComponentFoo;
```

Comment: How is the component model value intended to be determined / set?

Comment: @Seth Good question, updated the question with the answer

Comment: Why don't you set `ComponentFoo.model = 'blue'` explicitly in the pages that require it? You can't default it because it's not a property that the Next.js pages have by default, so your only option is the set it on all pages (either `blue` or `red`).

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good candidate for Next.js Layouts. You would have to compose a `Layout` component, similar to `Blue` in your example, which accepts a `color` prop and encapsulates the color rendering logic to the layout file. You can implement a default render path if no `color` prop is provided.

Then you can use it like so:

```js
// pages/whatever.tsx
import type { ReactElement } from 'react'
import Layout from '../components/layout'

export default function Page() {
  return {
    /** Your content */
  }
}

Page.getLayout = function getLayout(page: ReactElement) {
  return (
    <Layout color="blue">
      {page}
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts#with-typescript

Comment: to be clear the original question just uses blue/red as an example. The real problem is not about controlling anything visual, it's a string value to control certain authentication flows. So in that case I don't feel like setting that prop in a Layout makes a lot of sense

Comment: Ahh it wasn't clear from your original question that these values were a product of the authenticated user. How are you currently capturing your authenticated user's data and persisting it to each page?

Comment: It's not really about user data. It's about setting a certain value for a page to determine whether or not an unauthenticated user is allowed to access it.

Comment: See https://dev.to/nandkishoryadav/create-protected-routes-in-nextjs-and-nextauth-19ml

Comment: Still sounds like you'll want to do that at a page level. With next.js it's not very easy to determine authentication at the `_app.tsx` level without leveraging something like `getInitialProps`, which we should note opts you into server-side rendering. But if you want each page to determine its layout based on an authentication predicate then that might be a good place to start.